# Adding text into a PDF button with 1 click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, button, text, field

I'm creating a staff document which requires only 2 things to be unlocked.
1. A placeholder for an image, I've implemented that just fine by creating a button with "Icon only" and using a javascript code as follows:

```
// Mouse Up script to import a button icon
event.target.buttonImportIcon();
```

It works perfectly!
However I also need a text field which can be clicked once, and have text filled in and saved, because quite frankly the people that will be using the document, couldn't edit a PDF if the human race depended on it haha

Any help would be appreciated greatly!!! Thanks!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Oh, well my question was if anyone knew any javascript code like the one I have showed, that will enable a button on 1 click, to enter information and saved.

Answer (score 0):

Create a text field (which I'm assuming you will want to start off as empty) and then add the following command to activate on Mouse Down:

```
(this.getField("TextFieldName")).value = "The text that you want to add...";
```

Where `TextFieldName` is the reference to the text field that you want to auto fill.

This will make the text appear when the text field is clicked. You could add a clear button using similar code so that erroneous clicks can be undone. Also, you could set the field to be read only to prevent unwanted changes to the auto filled text.